# Managing a list of urls to redirect according to language in Asp.net Web Forms

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web, webforms

I have a web site developed with Asp.Net Web Forms (.Net Framework 4.6). I have two languages and many content pages. If a user in page clicks to language button then users redirected to same content's opposite language. For example if i am in contact page and if i click to spanish language button i am going to contact page in spanish which is a diffent web form.

To achive that i have a list of if statement like that:

```
if (ThePageIClickOnLanguageButton == "Help") { Response.Redirect("/Ayuda", false); }
if (ThePageIClickOnLanguageButton == "Sign-In") { Response.Redirect("/Iniciar-Sesion", false); }
if (ThePageIClickOnLanguageButton == "Support") { Response.Redirect("/Asistencia", false); }
if (ThePageIClickOnLanguageButton == "Products") { Response.Redirect("/Productos", false); }
```

So to achive same thing in the spanish pages i have to do same thing opposite like that:

```
if (ThePageIClickOnLanguageButton == "Ayuda") { Response.Redirect("/Help", false); }
if (ThePageIClickOnLanguageButton == "Iniciar-Sesion") { Response.Redirect("/Sign-In", false); }
if (ThePageIClickOnLanguageButton == "Asistencia") { Response.Redirect("/Support", false); }
if (ThePageIClickOnLanguageButton == "Productos") { Response.Redirect("/Products", false); }
```

My pages keep increasing so i am adding new lines all the time in to this if list.

There must be a better way to achive this. Like making a list like below list and create a method to find current page, look in to the list, find the url of other language and redirect it to there.

```
/Help       = /Ayuda
/Sign-In    = /Iniciar-Sesion
/Support    = /Asistencia
/Products   = /Productos
```

Any idea how to achive that?

Comment: What about saving values in DB?

Comment: Could be, but even though we should get this list in a code and processing it. Since everytime when i add a page i have to change the code i did not require placing list in the db. Even if i, i did not figured out how to keep the list in code and process it.